# Lista de todos arquivos que estão dentro da pasta Resource.Raw

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Como fazer para pegar todos os arquivos que estão na pasta Resource e passar para uma lista.

Estou fazendo manualmente, mas agora preciso pegar dinamicamente e passar para uma lista todos os arquivos que estão na pasta Resource.Raw

```
string[] caminho = new string[2];
caminho[0] = "android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Drawable.a;
caminho[1] = "android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Drawable.b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Algo como isto poderia resolver:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/", "*.*")
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mp4"));
var caminho = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in files)
{
     caminho.Add("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + item);
}
```

- Directory para pegar todos arquivos do seu diretório (alterar de acordo com o necessário).
- Foreach para preencher uma lista dos seus arquivos.

Comment: Após saber os nomes dos arquivos que estão na pasta como faço para concatenar o endereço completo da pasta com os nomes dos arquivos?

Comment: Thiago só reforçando o que quero mesmo é pegar todos os arquivos mp4 da pasta com os seus endereços completos pois eles serão todos reproduzidos.

Comment: Bom dia Luiz, alterei a função para pegar somente arquivos .mp4, e depois adicionar na lista os arquivos já concatenados... Só checa, para ver se o caminho vai ser este mesmo.